# Is programming mobile devices using eclipse dead?

Tags: eclipse, sdk, java-me

I cut my teeth so to speak with eclipse.

Learning Java and even programming mobile devices using Eclipse was a rewarding experince. My last and not so favorable encounter using this platform was **Pulsar**. But all references to it has disappeared in the new version of Eclipse called **indigo**. I just like to know if anyone still recommends eclipse when programming mobile device whether J2ME or any other device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue using Eclipse for developing mobile applications with Indigo release as well. Eclipse Pulsar was a packaging of several Eclipse projects for a providing an all in one download. Pulsar package is discontinued on the indigo release because it lacked the volunteers to support it. However all the projects that were part of the Pulsar are available on indigo release with their new versions.

For JavaME development you can install the eclipse [MTJ](http://www.eclipse.org/mtj) (mobile tools of Java) using the eclipse [update manager](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-124.htm).

Answer (score 3):

While Java ME is waning in popularity, Eclipse is now the platform of choice for developing for Android devices (see ADT). I believe Blackberry also has Eclipse-based tooling. What's left is iOS and Windows Phone. For iOS, I have heard some people using Eclipse CDT for development, but it's not a first-class experience due to lack of support from Apple. For Windows Phone, it's Dev Studio all the way.